# Python mixins how to differentiate same method?

Tags: python

From [here](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/mixins-and-python), if you define some objects like that:

```
class Mixin1(object):
    def test(self):
        print "Mixin1"

class Mixin2(object):
    def test(self):
        print "Mixin2"

class BaseClass(object):
    pass

class MyClass(Mixin2, Mixin1, BaseClass):
    pass
```

You'll get:

```
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.test()
Mixin2
```

Is there a way to call **`Mixin1`** `test()` method?

Comment: Do you want `obj.test()` to call `Mixin1.test()` or do you want to know how to be able to call both on `obj`?

Comment: There are lots of ways; it depends on why and where you want to circumvent Python's normal attribute lookup.

Comment: I want to be able to call `Mixin1.test()` via `obj`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it explicitly:

```
Mixin1.test(obj)
```

---

The attribute process in Python is relatively complex. For your given example, this is the process for finding the value of `obj.test`:

1. First, look at the instance itself. In this case, the instance does not have a `test` attribute.
2. Look at the class which `obj` is an instance of: `MyClass`. `MyClass` does not have a `test` attribute.
3. Start looking at the classes in the method resolution order of `MyClass`. In this case, `MyClass.__mro__` tells you to look first at `Mixin2`, then `Mixin1`, then `object`.
4. `Mixin2` has a `test` attribute, so we finally have a match.
5. `Mixin2.test` is a function with a `__get__` method, so that is called and the return value is used.

You can safely ignore step 5 here, and just assume that `Mixin2.test` is a method. One that is returned, you can see that `obj.test()` calls `Mixin2.test`.

This might help explain why I asked the question I did in a comment. There is a wide variety of ways you can fiddle with the program to get `obj.test()` to produce a call to `Mixin1.test()` instead. You can patch the object, you can fiddle with `MyClass.__mro__`, you can tweak what `Mixin2.test` actually does, etc.

Comment: It seems to me that, inheritance is redundant in this case then? As we can directly call `Mixin.test` in `MyClass.test`, we can still do it without `MyClass` inheriting from `Mixin`

Comment: I wouldn't say "redundant", just not able to handle every possible use case. The way multiple inheritance works, the OP's `MyClass` is "more" like a `Mixin2` than a `Mixin1`, so `Mixin2.test` is the method that `MyClass.test` resolves to. More work needs to go into overriding that behavior. (But honestly, inheriting from two unrelated classes define unrelated methods with the same name seems like a bad design decision; either `Mixin1` or `Mixin2`—or both—should have been adapted to provide unique names for `MyClass` to avoid the problem in the first place.)

Answer (score 5):

Override the `test` method and call `Mixin1.test` explicitly:

```
class MyClass(Mixin2, Mixin1, BaseClass):
    def test(self):
        Mixin1.test(self)
```